# SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal is excluded from policy but blocked

Tags: spfx-extensions, access, online

We want to exclude SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal from a certain block Conditional Access Policy. What different apps or what had to be excluded as a sub task as well? Because we see with whatif that everything should be opened correctly but using a normal user browser the SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application is blocked ...